# How can I put a variable in value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this in jquery.I need to put a variable in value is it possible to do this?

```
 var fieldHTML = '<div><input type="text" name="field_name[]" value="?"/></div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

use a templated string

```
 var fieldHTML = `<div><input type="text" name="field_name[]" value="${yourValueVar}"/></div>`;
```